# Mocking Delegate.Invoke() using Moq throws InvalidCast exception in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, delegates, moq

Let's say that I have `IService` interface:

```
public interface IService
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a delegate `Func<IService>` that returns this interface.

In my unit test I want to mock the delegate's `Invoke()` method using Moq like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTest()
{
    var mockService = new Mock<IService>();

    var mockDelegate = new Mock<Func<IService>>();
    mockDelegate.Setup(x => x.Invoke()).Returns(mockService.Object);

    // The rest of the test
}
```

Unfortunately `mockDelegate.Setup(...)` throws `System.InvalidCastException`:

> Test method
>   UnitTest threw exception:
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to
>   type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression'.
>
> at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.GetCallInfo(LambdaExpression expression, Mock mock)
>
> at Moq.Mock.<>c_*DisplayClass1c`2.b*_1b()
>
> at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Func`1 function)
>
> at Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Condition condition)
>
> at Moq.Mock`1.Setup(Expression`1 expression)
>
> at UnitTest() in UnitTests.cs: line 38

Line 38 is `mockDelegate.Setup(x => x.Invoke()).Returns(mockService.Object);`

Am I missing something? Or mocking delegate invocation is generally not a good idea?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no reason to do that. Just make a delegate yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Still interesting why there is an exception though...

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze The exception is there because because this scenario is not supported by Moq but instead of the throwing a NotSupportException you get this not so nice InvalidCastException. Which is a bug in my opion so the exception type should be fixed here... but you should anyway don't mock the delegate just write: `Func<IService> mockDelegate = () => mockService.Object;`

Comment: Yeah, did exactly that. Thank you for the details on the exception.

Comment: Added comments summary as an answer. Will accept it tomorrow if nobody care to put another one.

Comment: @nemesv If you see my answer you can see this scenario is supported by Moq, the exception is because the configuration of the delegate is being done incorrectly.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is 100% possible to do this in Moq, here is how:

```
var mockService = new Mock<IService>();

var mockDelegate = new Mock<Func<IService>>();
mockDelegate.Setup(x => x()).Returns(mockService.Object);
```

The reason you were getting the `InvalidCastException` was because you are creating a `Mock<T>` of a delegate type. Thus it is expecting the `Expression` to be of type `InvocationExpression` (`x()`) rather than `InstanceMethodCallExpressionN` (`x.Invoke()`).

This also allows you to verify invocations of your `Mock` delegate, e.g.

```
mockDelegate.Verify(x => x(), Times.Once);
```

I have posted this as an answer because while it may not be necessary for this situation, it can certainly be useful to know.

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely try today.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Worked

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is a summary of `SLaks` and `nemesv` comments.**

There is no reason to mock `Func<IService>` `delegate` in the first place. Instead one can write:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTest()
{
    var mockService = new Mock<IService>();

    Func<IService> mockDelegate = () => mockService.Object;

    // The rest of the test
}
```

The exception is there because because this scenario is not supported by Moq. But instead of throwing a `NotSupportException` you get not so nice `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: As demonstrated in my answer, this IS supported by Moq, the `InvalidCastException` is because the feature is being used incorrectly.