# Using Moq to mock Func<T> that behaves differently when called multiple times

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

How can a C# Func be mocked so it returns different values or exceptions when invoked multiple times?

```
Mock<Func<bool>> mock = new Mock<Func<bool>>();
mock.SetupSequence(m => m.Invoke())
    .Throws<Exception>()
    .Returns(true);
```

When run, the following exception is raised:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type
'System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression'.
```

I've seen another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755726/how-do-you-create-a-moq-mock-for-a-func/8756728#8756728) about using `SetupSet`, however, I need a sequence.

Comment: I think your answer lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297583/mocking-delegate-invoke-using-moq-throws-invalidcast-exception-in-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the tip to another answer from @henrikmerlander, the solution is to simply not use the `.Invoke` method.

```
Mock<Func<bool>> mock = new Mock<Func<bool>>();
    mock.SetupSequence(m => m())
        .Throws<Exception>()
        .Returns(true);
```